# Tomcat, Mod_rewrite, Mod_proxy: how do I keep the original URI path in a proxied request?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I'm using the following configuration to proxy requests and rewrite urls from Apache to Tomcat using mod_rewrite, mod_proxy.

```
# In apache virtual hosts

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

...
# In .htaccess file

#forward non-resource URL to jsp
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ http://localhost:8080/mycontext/$1.jsp [P]
```

My question: is it possible to instruct Tomcat to keep the original URI so that I can read it using a request.getRequestURI()?  Is this configuration possible or do I have to resort to mod_jk or some other proxy Connector?

The host name is retained currently... not the request path.  I'm also using Apache 2.2 and Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A not too cumbersome solution:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ http://localhost:8080/mycontext/$1.jsp&_requri_=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Then read the request uri from the _requri_ query parameter.

If there's a better way, please let me know.